# How do I assign a template to the user edit form?

Tags: theming, users

I am trying to create a twig template for user edit page.

I have tried

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_alter().
 */
function my_module_user_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  if($variables['element']['#type'] == 'form' && $variables['element']['#form_id'] == 'user_form') {
    $original_theme_hook = $variables['theme_hook_original'];
    $suggestions[] = $original_theme_hook . '__bs_' . str_replace('-', '_', $variables['element']['#id']);
  }
  return $suggestions;
}
```

I have added my template in my module under templates/form__bs_user_form.html.twig

I have also added in my form_alter:

```
$form['#theme'] = ['bs_user_form'];
```

and

```
function my_module_user_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'bs_user_form' => [
      'render element' => 'form',
      ],
  ];
}
```

It does retrieve this error:
Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Render\Element::setAttributes() must be of the type array, null given

How can I assign a template to the user edit form?

---

Solved, I removed my_module_user_theme_suggestions_alter and I got it working.
If anyone has a better solution feel free to add it to the answers.

Comment: why you need theme suggestions? you don't add any new information. you could simply use  `bs_user_form.html.twig`.
if you alter theme suggestions, keep `bs_user_form` and append the extra information at the end of the name with a double underscore.

Comment: Suggestions was my first option while googling. Then I added $form['#theme'] = ['bs_user_form']; but some how it was conflicting with suggestions. I removed suggestions and got it working. Thanks

Comment: you are asking for a better solution, this is the solution, you need only theme suggestions if you want to select templates depending on extra information, which you don't have at the moment

Comment: Cool, write it in the answers so I can accept it. Could you also add how to make the twig template available to my theme please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add an additional template level to a form, add the `#theme` key to the form array:

```
$form['#theme'] = ['bs_user_form'];
```

and in *my_module.module*:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'bs_user_form' => [
      'render element' => 'form',
      ],
  ];
}
```

The template name is then `bs-user-form.html.twig`, where you can print the form with `{{ form }}` or theme it like for example:

*entity-moderation-form.html.twig*

```
<ul class="entity-moderation-form">
  <li>{{ form.current }}</li>
  <li>{{ form.new_state }}</li>
  <li>{{ form.revision_log }}</li>
  <li>{{ form.submit }}</li>
</ul>
{{ form|without('current', 'new_state', 'revision_log', 'submit') }}
```

---

You can add theme suggestion to the theme name, but don't use `form__` as base hook, because this is already used for the [Form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Form.php/class/Form/8.3.x) element, which caused the error.

Comment: custom.css is not getting affected, If I use above steps. How do I solve this