# How to access to form field in views-exposed-form.html.twig (exposed filters)

Tags: views, theming

I am trying to customize the template for the exposed filters of a view.

I have created the `views-exposed-form.html.twig` and Drupal loads it fine, following [How do I theme exposed filters?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239785/how-do-i-theme-exposed-filters?rq=1).

For now, I have the standard code:

```
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override of a views exposed form.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - form: A render element representing the form.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_views_exposed_form()
 */
#}
{% if q is not empty %}
  {#
    This ensures that, if clean URLs are off, the 'q' is added first,
    as a hidden form element, so that it shows up first in the POST URL.
  #}
{{ q }}
{% endif %}
{{ form }}
```

and that works fine. Nevertheless, if I try to show only one field of the form (e.g., `{{ form.field_city }}`) nothing is shown in the filter block, though the page loads fine and there are no apparent errors.

I am working with Drupal 8.7.7 and PHP 7.3.9.

Any help will be more than welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need `{{ form|without('field1', 'field2', ...) }}` at some point, excluding all fields you have already printed or don't want to print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem seems to be an incompatibility with Better Exposed Filters module.

Thanks!